# how to modify bash_profile with cookiecutter path

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed cookiecutter with PIP3.
However, my bash_profile was not modified. 
When I type "cookiecutter" in the terminal I get "command not found".
here is my current bash_profile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I tried to add the following line:
    export PATH = "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.6/bin/cookiecutter"

It wasn't recognize either. 
Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try and source your bash_profile after edit, or try to logout and login again.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I'm assuming, the path to cookiecutter is correct :)